# Rosaria connection through USB adapter

Tags: ros, orocos, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to define an Orocos component for controlling the movement of a Pioneer3dx.

For doing that I installed the Orocos and ROSARIA stacks.

Now the problem is that I cannot connect to my robot. It is connected to the pc through and USB adapter and the aria library looks by default for the serial port.

I tried to use these coomands:

```
ArSerialConnection serialCon;
serialCon.setPort("/dev/ttyUSB0");
robot.setDeviceConnection(&serialCon);
```

However the application still locks for the serial port and not for the usb.
How can I fix it?

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12686/rosaria-connection-through-usb-adapter/) by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2012-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm not very familiar with Orocos, but are you sure that you are using ROSARIA to connect to the robot? USB to serial is the default in ROSARIA (/dev/ttyUSB0) and you can change it using port parameter, e.g. `rosrun ROSARIA RosAria _port:=/dev/ttyUSB1` in case you have something else on `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

If you are using Aria library directly (from Aria metapackage), take a look at RosAriaNode::Setup() method:

```
ArArgumentBuilder *args;
args = new ArArgumentBuilder();
args->add("-rp"); //pass robot's serial port to Aria
args->add(serial_port.c_str());
// left out irrelevant code
conn = new ArSimpleConnector(args);
// left out irrelevant code
// Connect to the robot
if (!conn->connectRobot(robot)) {
  ArLog::log(ArLog::Terse, "rotate: Could not connect to robot! Exiting.");
  return 1;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [JKS](https://answers.ros.org/users/357/jks/) with karma: 306 on 2012-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2012-01-19**:
@JKS Thank! Yes, actually I think I'm using Aria and not ROSARIA. Is there a tutorial for ROSARIA? Btw, I tried to apply you code and it works!!! Thanks!!

**Comment by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on 2012-10-19**:
Can you setup ROSARIA to use a TCP instead of a serial connection? If so how? In the source code I noticed that the arguments -rh (remotehost) and -rrtp (remote port) are passed. But if Iuse RosAria -rh IP -rrtp PORT it still tries the serial connection.